# How can I store application specific info in web.config such as number of threads to be run?

Tags: asp.net, configuration, web-config

I have a module that uses multithreading. I want to store the number of threads to be created by the module in the `web.config` file.

What tag should I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put it in the appSettings section.

```
  <appSettings>
      <add key="myModuleThreadCount" value="4" />
  </appSettings>
```

Then in your code, reference it as so:

```
  var threads = int.Parse( WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myModuleThreadCount"] );
```

Comment: thanks.the module from which i am using multithreading is not part of website .this module's dll is being refered in website.so i'm not able to access class WebConfigurationManager within this module.what should i do?

Comment: You should still be able to use ConfigurationManager to access the web.config file.  It will look in web.config -- at least it will if there is no specific .config file for that dll.  I use web.config to supply connection strings to my DAL this way.